# clicking row in datagridview make PDF file in database column appear in axAcroPDF1

Tags: c#, mysql

```
if  (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            var dataa = (Byte[])(row.Cells["pdf_appf"].Value);
            var streamm = new MemoryStream(dataa);
          //  axAcroPDF1.src = File.FromStream(streamm);   
          //last line is wrong      
        }
```

is it possible to make it appear
last line is wrong or all line?
halp thanks